# Knockout JSON null when received from service

Tags: wcf, knockout.js, json.net

I have an object which I wish to send to a WCF service, but object dosent get properly converted to be used on the other side as the ActiveFarmer and Evidence are always null. I have tested it with a hardcoded JSON and it works but the knockout object is not coming through properly, the object is as follows

```
 self.afi = {


    ActiveFarmer: {
        ActiveFarmerID: ko.observable(),
        BusinessID: ko.observable(),
        Year: ko.observable(),
        StatusID: ko.observable(),
        Status:ko.observable(),
        DecisionDate: ko.observable(),
        UserID: ko.observable(""),         
        DateModified: ko.observable(),


       // RowStatus: ko.observable(""),

    },

    // TODO - RH we used to add a default empty new line here...
    ActiveFarmerEvidence: ko.observableArray(),

    NotepadIdentifiers: ko.observableArray()

};
```

I am calling a wcf service

```
public int UpdateFarmerInfo(ActiveFarmerInfo afi)
{
    return ActiveFarmerInfoManager.UpdateFarmerInfo(afi);
}
```

My ajax call is as follows

```
 var afi = vm.afi;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: rootcap + "ActiveFarmerService.svc/rest/UpdateFarmer",                                
        data: JSON.stringify(afi),
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,

        success: function (data, textStatus) {

            self.populateFarmerDetails(data);


        },
        error: function (data, status, error) { }
    });
```

The entire view model is

```
function ActiveFarmerModel() {
var self = this;


self.businessId = ko.observable();
self.individualId = ko.observable();
self.currentAppId = ko.observable();

self.userId = ko.observable();
self.evidenceCategories = ko.observableArray();
self.activeFarmerEvidenceCategories = ko.observableArray();
self.businessStatus = ko.observableArray([{ "intStatusID": "2", "vcrStatus": "Provisionally Non-Oct" }, { "intStatusID": "1", "vcrStatus": "Active" }, { "intStatusID": "3", "vcrStatus": "Negative List" }, { "intStatusID": "4", "vcrStatus": "Active (Non Verified)" }])
self.currentStatus = ko.observable();
self.oldStatus = self.currentStatus();
self.ActiveFarmerID = ko.observable();
self.currentYear = ko.observable();
self.years = ko.observableArray([{ "intYearID": "5", "year": "2014" }, { "intYearID": "6", "year": "2015" }]);
self.businessStartDate = ko.observable();
self.DateFromServer = ko.observable(moment(new Date()).format('L')),
self.individualDOB = ko.observable();
self.businessName = ko.observable();
self.countyOfficeId = ko.observable();
self.individualDetails = ko.observable();
self.indDobOuterHTML = ko.observable();


self.evidenceTypes = ko.observableArray();

self.evidenceItem = function (evidenceData) {
    var self = this;

    if (evidenceData === null) {
        self.EvidenceCategoryID = ko.observable(-1);
        self.DateModified = ko.observable(moment(new Date()).format('L'));
        self.DateReceipted = ko.observable(moment(new Date()).format('L'));
        self.DocReceiptID = ko.observable("");
        self.EvidenceID = ko.observable(-1);
        self.EvidenceTypeID = ko.observable(-1);
        self.Other = ko.observable("");
        self.ReceiptedBy = ko.observable("");
        //self.RowStatus = ko.observable("I");
        self.TrimRecord = ko.observable("");
        self.TrimRecordDocReceipt = ko.observable("");
        self.UserID = ko.observable('NIGOV\1284535');

        self.selectedCategory = ko.observable(6);
    }
    else {
        self.EvidenceCategoryID = ko.observable(6);

        self.DateModified = ko.observable(moment(evidenceData.DateModified).format('L'));
        self.DateReceipted = ko.observable(moment(evidenceData.DateReceipted).format('L'));

        self.DocReceiptID = ko.observable(evidenceData.DocReceiptID);
        self.EvidenceID = ko.observable(evidenceData.EvidenceID);
        self.EvidenceTypeID = ko.observable(evidenceData.EvidenceTypeID);
        self.Other = ko.observable(evidenceData.Other);
        self.ReceiptedBy = ko.observable(evidenceData.ReceiptedBy);
        self.RowStatus = ko.observable(evidenceData.RowStatus);
        self.TrimRecord = ko.observable(evidenceData.TrimRecord);
        self.TrimRecordDocReceipt = ko.observable(evidenceData.TrimRecordDocReceipt);
        self.UserID = ko.observable(evidenceData.UserID);
        self.selectedCategory = ko.observable(6)

    }
    self.filteredSubCategories = ko.computed(function () {

        self.EvidenceCategoryID = self.selectedCategory();
        var ret = ko.observableArray();
        var filterAll = ko.observableArray();
        ret().push({ EvidenceTypeID: -1, EvidenceTypeDescription: "Please Select..." });

        if (self.selectedCategory()) {

            filterAll = ko.utils.arrayFilter(vm.evidenceTypes(), function (item) {
                return item.EvidenceCategoryID === self.selectedCategory();
            });
            for (var i = 0; i < filterAll.length; i++) {
                ret().push(
                {
                    EvidenceTypeID: filterAll[i].EvidenceTypeID,
                    EvidenceTypeDescription: filterAll[i].EvidenceTypeDescription,
                    EvidenceCategoryID: filterAll[i].EvidenceCategoryID
                });
            };

            return ret();
        }

        return [];

    }, self);

};



self.NotePad = {

    notes: ko.observableArray([
    { DateOfEntry: "01/05/2014", UserName: "John", EntryType: "Change Status", NoteText: "Status Changes to Active(Non Verified)" }
    ])

};
// Active Farmer Information
self.afi = {


    ActiveFarmer: {
        ActiveFarmerID: ko.observable(),
        BusinessID: ko.observable(),
        Year: ko.observable(),
        StatusID: ko.observable(),
        Status:ko.observable(),
        DecisionDate: ko.observable(),
        UserID: ko.observable(),         
        DateModified: ko.observable(),


    },


    ActiveFarmerEvidence: ko.observableArray(),

    NotepadIdentifiers: ko.observableArray()

};
```

}

```
 public class ActiveFarmerInfo 
{
    public ActiveFarmerInfo()
    {

    }

    protected override string GetSchemaName()
    {
        return "ActiveFarmer";
    }
    [XmlIgnore]


    public int ActiveFarmerID { get; set; }

    [DataMember, XmlElement]
    public ActiveFarmer ActiveFarmer { get; set; }

    // To contain the list for Active Farmer Application Evidences based on Active Farmer Id and Year
    [DataMember, XmlElement]
    public List<Evidence> ActiveFarmerEvidence { get; set; }

    public Int32 BusinessId { get; set; }
    public Int32 Year { get; set; }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

All the properties of the view model are knockout observable functions. So calling `JSON.stringify` to a view model with that kind of properties will not produce valid json. Try  changing `JSON.strngify` to `ko.toJSON` This function produces valid json string from a knockout view model. Something like this:

```
var afi = vm.afi;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: rootcap + "ActiveFarmerService.svc/rest/UpdateFarmer",                                
    data: ko.toJSON(afi),
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    cache: false,

    success: function (data, textStatus) {

        self.populateFarmerDetails(data);


    },
    error: function (data, status, error) { }
});
```

Notice the data property of the object passed to `$.ajax` function.

Comment: Hi, That dosent work, i tried passing my hardcoded JSON into this  ko.toJSON also, and it did not work, do I have to include anything else to get ko.toJSON to work ? sorry

Comment: Can you post the initialization of your view model, so I can get a better grasp on what's happening? And also the definition of the `ActiveFarmerInfo` class?

Comment: You do not need to pass the json to the ko.toJSON function. This function creates json from a knockout view model.

Comment: Thanks, would be very greatful if you can reccomend a solution. Thanks